# UITextView Autocomplete modification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm currently using this [HTAutocompleteTextField](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField/) to fill in a `UITextField` with a predefined list, should A user start typing in an entry that already exists. There are a couple of problems that I've been having however. The first is that it seems to stop when a comma is typed in (but not apostrophes). I've been looking around and I'm really not sure why it's doing it. I thought at one point it could be that the comma was a different comma, like an apostrophe issue I had due to importing the list from a word document. However, it wasn't the case. The second issue is more of an addition which I'm not really sure how to implement. I also want the autosuggest to detect suggestions for words in mid string, not just from the beginning. So for instance typing in "String" would suggest "This is a String". This currently how it does the auto suggest, but I have no idea how to do the above things.

```
NSString *prefixLastComponent = [componentsString.lastObject stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:space];
    if (ignoreCase)
    {
        stringToLookFor = [prefixLastComponent lowercaseString];
    }
    else
    {
        stringToLookFor = prefixLastComponent;
    }

    for (NSString *stringFromReference in colorAutocompleteArray)
    {
        NSString *stringToCompare;
        if (ignoreCase)
        {
            stringToCompare = [stringFromReference lowercaseString];
        }
        else
        {
            stringToCompare = stringFromReference;
        }

        if ([stringToCompare hasPrefix:stringToLookFor])
        {
            return [stringFromReference stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:[stringToCompare rangeOfString:stringToLookFor] withString:@""];
        }

    }
```

If anyone could give me any pointers on how to get this done, I'd appreciate it.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to go about solving both issues. For any one who uses this Git Repository, the reason why commas don't work when using the preset methods is because of `NSArray *componentsString = [prefix componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`. Remove the comma so it's `NSArray *componentsString = [prefix componentsSeparatedByString:@""];` and it should work nicely. To fix the other problem where it only detects the start of words, I changed the methods a little. Here are my changes in HTAutocompleteManager.m

```
int i = 0;
    for (NSString *stringFromReference in colorAutocompleteArray)
    {
        NSString *stringToCompare;
        if (ignoreCase)
        {
            stringToCompare = [stringFromReference lowercaseString];
        }
        else
        {
            stringToCompare = stringFromReference;
        }

        if ([stringToCompare hasPrefix:stringToLookFor])
        {
            //NSLog(@"Removing String: %@ atIndex: %d", [colorAutocompleteArray objectAtIndex:i], i);
            [colorAutocompleteArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [colorAutocompleteArray insertObject:stringFromReference atIndex:0];
            //NSLog(@"Adding String atIndex 0: %@", stringFromReference);

            return [stringFromReference stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:[stringToCompare rangeOfString:stringToLookFor] withString:@""];
        }
        else if ([stringToCompare hasSuffix:stringToLookFor] && ([stringToLookFor length] >= 3)) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", stringFromReference];
        }
        else if (!([stringToCompare rangeOfString:stringToLookFor].location == NSNotFound) && ([stringToLookFor length] >= 3))
        {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", stringFromReference];
        }
        ++i;
    }
```

The reason for reordering the Array is because after the 3rd character is typed it will prioritise the other two if statements because they will be reached first if there is a generic term in multiple entries in the array (like "Street" in a list of locations). I know it's not necessary to have the "hasSuffix" if statement, but I left it in case someone wants to use it on it's own. Lastly, I added in a space before `stringFromReference` so that it doesn't look weird when there's a suggestion straight after the input text. When we exit the `UITextField` we remove this space like this (inside `HTAutocompleteTextField.m - commitAutocompleteText`):

```
NSString *currentText = self.text;
if ([self.autocompleteString isEqualToString:@""] == NO
    && self.autocompleteDisabled == NO)
{
    if ([self.autocompleteString hasPrefix:@" "]) {
        self.autocompleteString = [self.autocompleteString substringFromIndex:1];
    }
    self.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.autocompleteString];

    self.autocompleteString = @"";
    [self updateAutocompleteLabel];
}
return ![currentText isEqualToString:self.text];
```

Hope this makes sense to anyone who's in a similar situation.

Mike